# AngularJS: filterting/searching based on formatted date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a table in AngularJS which I used filter to do the searching functionality.

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse |filter:searchValue">
```

In the table, I have a date field which I formatted and displayed in MM/dd/yyyy:

```
<td>
     {{order.OrderDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}
</td>
```

The issue is, the original date type is something like: '2015-10-30' and the filtering will be based on that. So if I search for 10/30/2015, it will return nothing. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a method in scope

Like this

```
$scope.filterValue=function(obj){
  return $filter('date')(obj.OrderDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') == $filter('date')($scope.searchValue, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
}
```

Add this method to your html's filter

Like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse |filter:filterValue">
```

N:B:

you have to inject `$filter` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jsod6hur/)**

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.order = {};
    $scope.order.OrderDate = "2015-10-30";


    $scope.parseDate = function(input) {
        var parts = input.split('-');
        return new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]);
    };
});
```

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
    {{parseDate(order.OrderDate) | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}
</div>
```

**output**

```
10/30/2015
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But for my case, the formatting works pretty fine. But the searching / filtering is based on the unformatted date, not the formatted one.

Comment: @Nidhish op's problem was in searching not in display, may be ?

Comment: @LanceShi Is there any restriction in searchValue ? or your searchValue will be always in `MM/dd/yyyy:` ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi will always be MM/dd/yyyy I suppose, since that is what displayed

Answer (score -1):

or if you can return additional column in record set as formatted date

```
JobStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Record[5]),
JobStartDateSearch = Convert.ToDateTime(Record[5]).ToShortDateString(),
```

Where `JobStartDate` represents actual date object
`JobStartDateSearch` will represent formatted date string. So in search textbox if you type date string e.g. 5/14/2018, that will match with `JobStartDateSearch` and record will be filtered.